# How to get http status code directly into a variable in cURL lib?

Tags: curl, libcurl, http-status

I know curl_easy_getinfo function can be used to get the http status code. Is there anyway to set a variable (curl_easy_setopt) and read value directly from it after performing the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you use [curl_easy_getinfo](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)() to extract information from the previous transfer. Even for HTTP response codes: [CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE.html).